# Require that part of regex range must be present while other is optional

Tags: php, regex

I have data like so:

```
01Jun18 324567645
01Jun18 Addfd
01Jun18 112 Word
01Jun18 fjfs7dfsfj
01Jun18 kdkd
01Jun18 0sdfnefk
01Jun18 skfks7sfsff
01Jun18 sfrfsf8srfsr
```

I want all lines except the first to match. The string can contain numbers, but it cannot except just numbers alone - there MUST be a letter present too.

So far I am using, but this matches all rows:

```
([\d]{2}[A-Za-z]{3}[\d]{2}) ([A-Za-z\d ]{1,})
```

Any ideas on how or if this can be achieved? I have tried using `+` to mark the A-Z as required

Comment: This may suffice `(?im)^\d\d[a-z]{3}\d\d (?!\d+$).+`. See live demo here  https://regex101.com/r/td85ta/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([\d]{2}[A-Za-z]{3}[\d]{2}) [0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z ]*$
```

Comment: Missing second capture group but otherwise it works great. Can't add them as edit is too short.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
preg_match_all('~^(\d{2}[A-Za-z]{3}\d{2})\h+(?!\d+$)([A-Za-z\d\h]+)$~m', $s, $matches)
```

You may even replace `([A-Za-z\d\h]+)` with `(.*)` if you just want to match the rest of the line without caring about what chars there may be.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1wRpai/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the line (due to `m` modifier)
- `(\d{2}[A-Za-z]{3}\d{2})` - Group 1: two digits, three ASCII letters, two digits
- `\h+` - 1 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(?!\d+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are only digits to the end of the line
- `([A-Za-z\d\h]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars that are letters, digits, or horizontal whitespaces
- `.*` - matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of the line.